# how to change the general JAVA COFFEE CUP icon in JAR file

Tags: java, jar, icons

I can change the JAVA COFFEE CUP icon in my Frame (up,left), but how could I change the RUNNABLE JAR file's general JAVA COFFEE CUP picture? Is it possible at all, to change only one JAR file's file icon? Thx

Comment: You mean, as displayed in Windows Explorer?

Comment: I'm assuming @victorio is making an executable `.jar` to distribute their program and would like the app's logo to be displayed instead of the generic jar logo like you can with an `.exe`.

Answer (score 4):

JAR file has no icon. It's the operating system that gives it an icon. You cannot change the icon of one JAR file without changing the icon of all JAR files.

Answer (score 2):

The icon displayed on jar file is OS dependent, OS recognizes this type of file as java file and assigns an icon,

Alternatively the faster way is to create shortcut and then right click on short cut and choose icon to change

Answer (score -3):

Extract the JAR file which is a ZIP, locate the icon file, modify it, repack the JAR file.